# Uncaught error when replacing original field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

So I want to replace field city with my custom model, but I get this error. I think maybe some domain trying to use old 'city' field, but I can't find it.

```
Uncaught Error: NameError: name 'city' is not defined
```

```py
from openerp import fields, models


class ResCity(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.city'
    _description = 'Res City'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
    country_id = fields.Many2one(
        'res.country', string='Country')


class ResCountry(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.country'

    city_ids = fields.One2many(
        'res.city', 'country_id', string="City's")


class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
city_id = fields.Many2one('res.city', string='City')
```

```xml
 <record id="view_contact_form" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">res.partner.view</field>
                <field name="model">res.partner</field>
                <field name="priority" eval="101"/>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="city_id" position="replace">
                        <field name="city_id" placeholder="City"/>
                    </field>
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='child_ids']/form//field[@name='city']" position="replace">
                        <field name="city_id" placeholder="City"/>
                    </xpath>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your snippet, you insert a reference to the `city` field, which would cause that error message. You'll need to replace references to `city` in the original form by references to your new field `city_id`:

```
<record id="view_contact_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.view</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="101"/>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='city']" position="replace">
            <field name="city_id" placeholder="Select city..."/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: i get this error Error details:
Element '<xpath expr="//field[@name='child_id']">' cannot be located in parent view

Comment: There's a typo in my xml; now corrected (child_ids instead of city_id)

Comment: Error details:
Field `city_ids` does not exist

Comment: Updated again; there was another typo